# Why can't I open a ContextMenu using the same menu variable twice?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I need to dynamically change the visibility and... enability? of context menu items, without having to use about fifteen booleans for larger applications with many menu options, so I thought I could modify the ContextMenu variable and then inflate it again, but it does not open again after opened once. Why's this?

I've tried closing it and opening, forcing to open it again (which only ends up in an infinite loop), and all manner of things. I've tried looking up the documentation and multiple questions here, as well as Google but I find nothing on why this is happening. I'm aware this isn't the "correct" way of handling contextMenus, but I want to know *why* this is happening.

```java
//Earlier in the activity
[...]
menu.getItem(0).setVisibility(false);
[...]

@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        if(this.menu == null){
            this.menu = menu;
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, this.menu);
        } else {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, this.menu);
        }
    }
```

The menu opens only once. It will not open again as long as I keep using the private variable "menu" (this.menu) Why is this? I'd like to know, as I figure knowing will help me understand how to properly fix the current design challenges I have.

Comment: What is the problem that you face and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Prajwal W I want to be able to modify the items dynamically throughout the activity without the use of control variables, and changing the items only in onCreateContextMenu, but the menu won't open twice using the same variable. I figured that asking WHY this happens would be a good first step to solve my problem.